# Restricción con pattern en XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

Es mi primera consulta en el foro, así que si hago algo mal pido perdón de antemano.
Estaba intentando hacer un ejercicio de XSD donde el elemento dirección debe estar formado por un conjunto de letras cualesquiera, después un espacio en blanco y por último, un número que está comprendido entre 1 y 200.
Para esto tengo que usar la restricción "pattern" y hablándolo con un compañero hemos pensado en ponerlo así:

```
   <xsd:element name="direccion">
     <xsd:simpleType>
      <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
       <xsd:pattern value="[a-z]*\b(200)|(1[0-9][0-9])|([1-9][0-9])|([1-9])"/>
      </xsd:restriction>
     </xsd:simpleType>
   </xsd:element>`
```

El problema es que no estaría del todo bien y además el validador me da fallo, no se si sabríais como cambiarlo para que cumpliera la norma y no diera error.
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Las expresiones regulares en XSD tienen algunas limitaciones: No soportan `^`, `$`, `\b` ni lookahead por mencionar algunos.

Intenta con: `.* (200|1?[0-9]{2}|[1-9])`

Comment: Muchas gracias Sal, ha funcionado. El .* tengo que averiguar que es y supongo que el espacio que hay hace que se convierta en restricción, separando las letras por los números con un espacio, ¿no?

Comment: Totalmente correcto.